# SQL data does not persist

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

Yesterday I updated some rows from a table,and today everything has changed back. It's the second time when it happened. Yesterday I thought I forgot to update the rows but now I realize that something it's wrong with database.
 What can cause that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: a haunted database perhaps.

Comment: Are you the only one using the database? If there are others, ask them, maybe someone restored a copy of the databse that didn't had your data.

Comment: My money would be on that - forgot to commit.

Comment: Yes I am the only one who have access to database. I updated the rows from Microsoft Sql Server so it's not necessary commit.

Comment: Do u have any triggers ?

Comment: maybe some job or something is running on sql-server. Also consider that not only people may access the database, but you applications (if any) that connect to db may have overriden you data because of sort of a bug,

Comment: If you are the only one using the database and no commit needed, then my friend, the error should be in something you are not correctly doing. Check the code you are running, double check that indeed the rows you wanted to updated where the correct ones, maybe you just misstyped some character and you updated other rows instead the ones you need.

Comment: Is this application in development phase ? If yes, there can be possibility of hard-coded values from application getting updated, which someone might have added for testing.

Comment: It happened again. I updated those rows. I saw rows updated in database with right values and than after one hour I rechecked and  I saw that columns came back to the previews values. The table do not have any trigger.

Comment: use profiler to capture all events which are taking place on the table & leave it running this should at least tell you if anything else is accessing the table after your insert

Comment: Finally I found out what happened. I checked every stored procedure from database and  found the one with problem.
Every time when that stored procedure is executed all values from that one column are updated because I forgot to put the condition.

So UPDATE table_name SET column_name=value instead UPDATE table_name SET column_name=value WHERE condition

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure autocommit is on:

SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF

Then run your update query

End your session and restart and see if your changes persisted.  If they did and disappear the following day, there's something else happening.  Are you on a virtual machine?